# Doing combinations of sub-sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

To create a `list` of all the possible combinations of a `sublist`.
I have a list, somewhat resembling the following format:

```
{{{a1, a2}, {b1}}, {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}}, {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}}}
```

I'm trying to get Mathematica to generate a list that is all the combinations of the contents of these sublists. So I'd get

```
{{a1, b1}, {a2, b1}, {a1, c1}, {a1, c2}, {a2, c1}, {a2, c2}, 
 {a1, c1, d1}, {a1, c1, d2}, {a1 ,c2 ,d1}, {a1, c2, d2}, {a2, c1, d1}, 
 {a2, c1, d2}, {a2, c2, d1}, {a2, c2, d2}}
```

It was suggested that I use a nested `For` loop to accomplish this, but I'm not entirely sure that would be the most efficient way to go about this.

Is there a clever way I could apply some combination of the mathematica list functions to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Welcome Andrew. Please look at the help section, especially the section about [how to format your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: `Catenate[Tuples /@ list]`

Answer (score 11):

What you want is something nice and clean like this

```
l = {{{a1, a2}, {b1}}, {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}}, {{a1, a2}, {c1, c2}, {d1, d2}}};
Join @@ (Tuples /@ l)
```